# Parameters Estimation using Least Square Method in Matlab

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I have the next questions:
Consider a set of equations `y=ax+b` where i know the y and x and want to estimate the `a` and `b` using least square method. 
Let's assume to have `Y=[y1 ; y2]` and
 `A=[x1 1; x2 1]` so that `Y=A*[a;b]`

According to least square method : 
`B=[a;b]=( transpose(A)*A )^-1*transpose(A)*Y`

1. `(A'*A) \ A'*Y` and `A\Y` are the same?
2. Which is the best method to calculate B:

   `inv( transpose(A)*A ) *transpose(A)*Y`

   `(transpose(A)*A) \ transpose(A)*Y`

   `(A'*A) \ A'*Y`

   `pinv(A)*Y` (calculate the pseudo-inverse matrix)

all the above give slightly different results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before solving your doubts, a remark is mandatory. When you want to transpose a matrix using the shorthand operator... you should not use `'`, but `.'`. The first one is the shorthand operator for the [conjugate transpose](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) while the second one is the correct shorthand operator to use for the [transpose](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html). While they normally produce the same result, using the former with matrices containing complex numbers could mess up your calculations.

Since you didn't provide a data sample, here are the settings I deployed for my tests:

```
Y = [2; 4];
A = [3 1; 7 1];
```

Now, let's go step-by-step. For what concerns your first answer, yes, the two operations are equivalent on a mathematical point of view and produce basically the same result:

```
>> B = A \ Y

B =
    0.5
    0.5

-----------------------------

>> B = inv(A.' * A) * A.' * Y

B =
    0.500000000000001
    0.5
```

The slight difference you see is due to the fact that `INV(A) * b` is less accurate than `A \ b`, and this is clearly stated even by the Matlab code interpreter if you hover a call to the `inv` function followed by a multiplication (which should be marked with an orange warning highlight):

[image: Warning]

This partially answers also your second question, but let's do an exhaustive benchmark. I discarded the computation performed using `inv(A.' * A) * A.' * Y` since it is recommended to avoid it. Here we go:

```
tic();
for i = 1:100000
    B = A \ Y;
end
toc();

tic();
for i = 1:100000
    B = pinv(A) * Y;
end
toc();

tic();
for i = 1:100000
    B = (A.' * A) \ A.' * Y;
end
toc();
```

This is the result of the benchmark:

```
Elapsed time is 0.187067 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.987651 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.173117 seconds.
```

Given that the three approaches have the same accurancy... the first one is by far, and obviously, the fastest one.